# How to remove whitener ink from the clothes?

Tags: cleaning, clothing

I just used whitener for marking the box, but due to force pressing it burst opened from the back and spilled fully over my clothes. Is there any best way to remove the spilled whitener?

It's the whitener used to erase words and not like whitener used for clothes or any other

[image: whitener correction pen]

Comment: Reading a little into this, was this "whitener" something like chalk powder used for marking lines on a sporting field?  What exactly it is is likely to affect the answers you receive.

Comment: Its a liquid ink white in colour, used to erase words

Comment: In the USA, this is commonly called "correction fluid".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most products of that type, in my experience, are more like a form of paint than ink.  That is, they're a latex based pigment carried in a water based solution, rather than a dye solution.  Most will come off with soap and water and scrubbing, especially before they're fully dry.  This obviously works best with durable clothing items; if you spilled this on a silk suit, take it to a professional, because you're more likely to completely destroy it than clean it, but if it's blue jeans, khaki, or similar sturdy stuff, get some soap, warm water, and a brush and scrub away.

Comment: +1 - in the 'old days' they were 'alcohol-based' so something like paint thinner or acetone/nail varnish remover would do the job. I think these days they're more like acrylic paint... which tends to be pretty much insoluble after it's dried. This link has some guides, though it's a [well-respected] cleaning product site so assumes use of its own products - https://www.persil.co.uk/laundry-tips/how-to-get-paint-out-of-clothes/

Comment: Acrylic and latex paint are different names for the same stuff -- artists mix wall paint with their expensive artist's acrylics routinely.  Either, if you can get it while it's still damp or wet, comes out easily with soap and water, but both are a PITA if fully dried.

Comment: For sure... though latex & acrylic are absolutely not the same thing. I've never even heard of 'latex paint', though I do remember some glues/adhesives being called 'rubber solution' way back in the day. Maybe it's a country/cultural/demographic/marketing... etc. generic rather than accurate descriptive term.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can try good detergent that promises you to remove ink spots.

If you can't find one, try following solutions:

1. Squeeze a lemon and put some drops of vinegar on that. Let it soak for half an hour and then wash it with soap.
2. Use Bleach for it.
3. You can also try a wet cotton ball. Tap it at stains and repeat it for a while. Use new cotton ball if required.
4. Pour salt on the stain and tap it with wet paper towel. Repeat this process until the stain is gone.